# C# Parameters class with app.config

Tags: c#, app-config

I have a configuration class with all the parameters of my application, to acquire images from a scanner.
I have parameters like color/BW, resolution...
The parameters are changed often, so I'm searching a solution to write automatically when I save the parameters the changed parameters in the app.config file. And to do the reverted thing, write my class from the app.config at the init of the software. 
Here are my two classes :

```
private void GetParameters() {
        try
        {
            var appSettings = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings;
            Console.WriteLine( ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MyKey"]);

            if (appSettings.Count == 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("AppSettings is empty.");
            }
            else
            {
                foreach (var key in appSettings.AllKeys)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Key: {0} Value: {1}", key, appSettings[key]);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (ConfigurationErrorsException)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error reading app settings");
        }
    }
    private void SetParameters(string key, string value)
    {
        try
        {
            Configuration configManager = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
            KeyValueConfigurationCollection confCollection = configManager.AppSettings.Settings;
            if (confCollection[key] == null)
            {
                confCollection.Add(key, value);
            }
            else
            {
                confCollection[key].Value = value;
            }
            configManager.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified);
            ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection(configManager.AppSettings.SectionInformation.Name);
        }
        catch (ConfigurationErrorsException)
        {

            MessageBox.Show("Error writing app settings");
        }

    }
```

I don't want to call the method for every parameter...
And there is my parameters class :

```
class ScannerParameters
{
    public bool Color { get; set; }

    public int Resolution{ get; set; }

    public string FilePath { get; set; }

    public TypeScan TypeScan { get; set; }

    public string TextTest{ get; set; }

}
```

Comment: So you mean that if someone changes the parameters in your app, that you want those values saved back to the config?

Comment: Exact that is the behaviour I'm searching.

Comment: Is it just not working? You don't really say what the trouble is, so it's a bit unclear what you need..

Comment: App.config was not designed to be written to.  If you want to persist data use a database, or a json file or literally anything else.

Comment: Okay so I will use a json file. Is there a specific "configuration json file" ? 
@DangerZone it is working, but I have to call the method for every parameter, everytime something changed.

Comment: Its easily written to.  I do it all the time.  If you just have a few user preference type keys, its pretty stupid to setup a whole database.

Comment: The question can be translated into how do I save an object into some kind of persistence? Either use a database or serialize it using some serializer or simply write it all down into a text file yourself. Using json serialization, serializing your ScannerParameters and then writing that into a file would seem most appropriate.

Comment: What part isn't working? Is it not saving the keys to the app.config, or is just not refreshing the keys after you save it?

Comment: why not implement something like INotifyPropertyChanged interface so that changes are perpetuated into the config.app file only when those respective properties are changed?

Comment: Thanks to @pijemcolu  I realized that what I needed was serialization. 
The INotifyPropertyChanged is also a good solution.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question can be translated into **how do I save an object into some kind of persistence?**

Either use a database (seems like an overkill) or serialize it using a serializer or simply write it all down into a text file yourself. Using json serialization, serializing your ScannerParameters and then writing that into a file would seem most appropriate.

Using newtonsoft json, which is defacto standard for .net there's nice examples @ http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializingJSON.htm

In your case you would do:

```
// our dummy scannerParameters objects
var parameters = new ScannerParameters();

// let's serialize it all into one string
string output = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(paramaters);

// let's write all that into a settings text file
System.IO.File.WriteAllText("parameters.txt", output);

// let's read the file next time we need it
string parametersJson = System.IO.File.ReadAllText("parameters.txt);

// let's deserialize the parametersJson
ScannerParameters scannerParameters = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ScannerParameters>(parametersJson);
```

Comment: Why a `.txt` file and not a `.json` file?

Comment: The parameter is a path and after all json is just text. `file.json` also seems scarier than `file.txt`. I guess it's just my personal preference. It is true though that calling the thing `file.json` is more descriptive.

Comment: Thanks, that is the solution I used. 
How to deserialize it to a ScannerParameters class ?

Comment: There is absolutely no reason not to write it to the app.config as the User originally asked for help on. Serializing to a file (whether it be Json or XML) is an option, especially if he was trying to store a complex object.  But for simple keys it is overkill.